# get referer from e-mail link

Tags: php, email, http-referer

Is it possible (and if yes, how) to get a referer, when a user clicks on a link in an e-mail? I can't use `<form>` tags in my e-mail, only pure links.

I want to display a special message, if a user visits my site when coming from my newsletter. I noticed however, that no referer ist provided when clicking on a link in (lets say outlook).

```
echo "Refererer " . ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : "Not provided");
```

When coming from another site, the referer works. I assume that there is no referer then? Is there a way to tell "yes, this user comes from the newsletter-link"?

One workaround I was thinking about is using `get-params`.

```
<a href="mysite.com/?ref=true">Visit now</a>
```

Without testing it, it should work, when I explicitly look for that `get-param`. This however is a way I don't want to go, since I'd like to have a clean **url**

```
mysite.com/
```

Any other ideas? Is it even doable with other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a custom referrer parameter, since many email clients (gmail being one) **explicitly** removes any referer information to prevent sites from tracking that you clicked the link from an email.

If you look at any newsletter you've received via email, you will see that this is the way it is usually done.

What you could do (if you haven't already done so) is to extract the functionality to get the "referer" into a common method that you can call, which will search through any available referrer information and pick the correct one.